# Need to show as loss or gain as a separate column based on the output in sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to show like loss/gain for a column based on the amount

If the result amount is `-10000` then I need to show as loss , if its `10000` means gain in sql query..

Here is my query if the output is negative then i should display the amount and one more column as loss and if the output is positive then i should display the amount and one more column as gain

```sql
select ((NVL (asset_cost, 0) - NVL (accumalated_dep, 0))- NVL (closed_lability, 0)) 
From Asset_management
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output. Your formulation allowes several *different* solutions...

Answer (score 0):

just wrap in a sub query or CTE to avoid typing it out again:

```
select value,case when value =-10000 then 'loss' case when value =10000 then 'gain' else '??' end
from
(
select ((NVL (asset_cost, 0) - NVL (accumalated_dep, 0))- NVL (closed_lability, 0))  as value
From Asset_management
) as calc
```

or

```
with
    (
    select ((NVL (asset_cost, 0) - NVL (accumalated_dep, 0))- NVL (closed_lability, 0))  as value
    From Asset_management
    ) as calc
    select value,case when value =-10000 then 'loss' case when value =10000 then 'gain' else '??' end
```

(approximate syntax due to no usable scripts)